# How can I edit the color of Python module names in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can't change the color of the module name in VS Code, Python code,

For example, my goal is to change the color of the "random" in "import random"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `module` semantic token type. Like so:

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    // optionally wrap the following in a "[Color Theme Name]": { ... }
    "rules": {
        "module:python": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

This will apply to all `module` semantic tokens in Python code. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-coloring-in-color-themes.

Or you could use the `entity.name.namespace` TextMate token scope. Like so:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    // optionally wrap the following in a "[Color Theme Name]": { ... }
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "entity.name.namespace",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#FF0000",
        }
    }]
},
```

This will apply to all `entity.name.namespace` TextMate tokens scopes in any language. See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme.

Both those solutions require the Python extension to be installed and enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.namespace",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#008000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).